# Specify QueryString Parameters in redirect_uri

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented Signup with facebook functionality, its working fine, now I have to specify a parameter in `redirect_uri`, I have specified it but when I am accessing FB, Its giving error:

> (OAuthException) Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

If my `redirect_uri` is this

```
http://localhost:5000/SignUp/FBOAuth
```

it works fine,but when I specify parameter like this(this parameter can have null value)

```
http://localhost:5000/SignUp/FBOAuth?CheckOut=
```

or

```
http://localhost:5000/SignUp/FBOAuth?CheckOut=
```

It starts giving error, Is it possible to specify parameters in `redirect_uri`? I have read on facebook developer's site that its a bug, [Here](http://developers.facebridge.net/bugs/589787261035915?browse=search_512d2c9d8a9a96143590858)

Comment: Are you adding this URL in your redirect URL of your app settings? or is it the redirect URL you are giving to return to when generating login URL

Comment: I am giving it when generating login URL